# IBM MobileFirst project and Git clone

Tags: eclipse, git, ibm-mobilefirst

I started working on MobileFirst project in a team environment and need to store the project in a git repo (hub.jazz.net).  From my local I can push all the working directory into git repo just fine, however if my team members clone the project from the repo, the resulting project in their Eclipse is not a MobileFirst project, but a regular project.  FYI .. they can create a MobileFirst project locally on their eclipse so I know they have the MobileFirst eclipse plugin installed.

I check in Eclipse - Configure, there is no option to convert the cloned project into a MobileFirst project.  Are there specific steps to clone MobileFirst project or on how to convert the cloned project into a MobileFirst project?

Comment: What do you have in your .gitignore? You might be ignoring an Eclipse config file that contains the metadata to indicate it is an MFP project.

Comment: Please see the following "mfp-gitignore" GIT project.  No support provided, but this is owned/managed by one of our best ISSW Services practictioner.

https://github.com/andrewferrier/mfp-gitignore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of hidden folders and files that must also be checked-in in order to preserve the project as a "MobileFirst project". These are the ".settings" folder and ".project" file (also the .classpath file for good measure).

To view them

- In Eclipse use the Navigator view
- In the Mac filesystem use the "ls -a" command in Terminal
- Or [use this](https://www.google.co.il/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mac%20show%20hidden%20files%20yosemite) to also see them in Finder

Please also note Karl's comment: when using Git or any other SCM you should be careful **not** to share some binary artifacts as documented in the Info Center.

Comment: Thank you Idan and Daniel for stating the obvious. Looks like it is missing the .project when I first uploaded it, somehow it is included in .gitignore file.